# ProgressHUD width size not changing UI

Tags: ios, swift

As I continue working on my fitness app to add features, I stumble occasionally.  I am having difficulty getting the ProgressHUD to update the view size.  I know that a value is sent to the properties of the view but the width does not change in the UI.  Here is the code I'm using for updating.

```
// linked to view that needs to change size when progressHUD is updated
@IBOutlet weak var progressHUD: UIView!


// this is set inside a timer that fires every 20 seconds and should update progressHUD

progressHUD.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width/10) * CGFloat((userHeartRate/Double(maxHeartRate)))
```

Here is the GUI:

[image: User interface]

The app gets the users current heart rate, compares it to the maximum heart rate to get a percentage of the maximum heart rate.  This percentage is represented by the progressHUD (gray bar beneath Warm Up) and should move to the right based on the percentage of the maximum heart rate.

I know that the values are calculating correctly and assigning the value to progressHUD.frame.size.width but the gray bar does not reflect the value assigned to it.

I have installed the cocoapod for ProgressHUD and I believe everything to be working correctly. (There were no errors on the install)

There must be something simple that I am overlooking!

Any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the progressHud objective. If we are talking about this one https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD it is not a progress BAR, it is a spinner to tell user some process is going on and they have to wait.

Comment: Why are you dividing `view.frame.size.width` by `10`?

Comment: I was way out in left field on this and you are exactly right.  I'm back with reality now and appreciate you bring this to my attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an unnecessary *divide by 10* in your formula.

If you want `progressHUD` to vary from 0% to 100% of the `width` of the `view's` frame. then you should do:

```
progressHUD.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(userHeartRate)/CGFloat(maxHeartRate)
```

Assuming `userHeartRate` doesn't exceed `maxHeartRate`, then `CGFloat(userHeartRate)/CGFloat(maxHeartRate)` is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`.  Multiplying that the the view's `width` gives a value 0% to 100% of the view's `width`.

You might want to throw in a `max()` function if `userHeartRate` can exceed `maxHeartRate`:

```
progressHUD.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width * max(1.0, CGFloat(userHeartRate)/CGFloat(maxHeartRate))
```

---

Since your `progressHUD` view is laid out in the Storyboard, you might want to use *Auto Layout* to size it.  Get an outlet to the constraint for the view's width:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressHUDwidth: NSLayoutContraint!
```

Then update it by setting its `constant` property:

```
progressHUDwidth.constant = view.frame.size.width * ...
```

Comment: I understood most of what you explained here except the outlet to the width constraint but figured that out.  It is work!  You have been a tremendous help and I truly appreciate your assistance.  Now that the progress bar is working, the zones are not directly correspond to the layout of 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.  Rather, warm up is up to 60%, fat burning from 60 - 74%, cardio 75 - 84% and peak 85 - 100%.  I'll put a conditional statement together to handle the progress bar appropriately.  The main thing is.... IT WORKS!  Thanks again!